# Using Paperclip to Form Image Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading

I have a database called stories.  I can create a story using the form and upload it to the database. I then have a show page where I display the name of the store and a link to view it.

I want to do the same things with pictures.  I want there to be two separate databases.  All the tutorials I come across tend to show you how to add avatars to a user model.  I don't want to do that.  I want to create a whole new second database.  Does anyone know of a tutorial out there like this?  I have been looking for days.  Is this possible?

Comment: don't you mean a new database table, rather than a whole new database? I'd recommend using Paperclip (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and integrating it into a model.

Comment: Yes sorry, new table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want store pictures in individual database table not other database right?

There's the same thing with add avatar to user model. Create a model named picture, and set a column to store image file name. The rest is following Paperclip doc to fill your picture model.